# Can Java Web Start application work inside browser window?

Tags: java, browser, java-web-start

This is the question: can JWS app occupy requin on web page or represent entire web page and/or access browser state parameters?

Comment: What exactly are *"browser state parameters"*?

Answer (score 2):

A Java Web Start application runs independently of the browser.  If you want a Java app to interact with the hosting browser, you have to make it an applet.

Comment: *"A Java Web Start application runs independently of the browser"*  Wrong, in recent times.  An embedded applet can be launched using JWS.  See my answer as well as the [GIFanim applet](http://pscode.org/gifanim/#applet) - it is launched using JWS sand-boxed & uses the JNLP API services to read/write to the local file-system.

Comment: @Andrew Thomson-- So JWS will start your browser with the applet in the page?

Comment: If you want to see how it works, follow the link to the applet.

Answer (score 1):

See the last link in the [applet info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info).

> - [JNLP Support in the Next Generation Java Plug-In Technology (introduced in **Java SE 6 update 10**)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jnlp-136707.html) goes into further details of the new abilities of applets.

I high-lit the version since it is a recent ability, and I got the impression you wanted to support older browser/JRE combos. from your earlier question.

That page expands..

> The next-generation Java Plug-In technology (hereafter the "Java Plug-In") provides support for launching applets directly from JNLP files. Previously, only Java Web Start utilized JNLP files, for the purpose of launching Java applications. Now Java applets can be described using the same meta-descriptor.

Also note that launching an embedded applet using JWS does not solve any of the problems that inherently come with embedding a rich client GUI into the lighter HTML GUI.

1. Focus problems between HTML elements and the applet or applets. Sun never bothered to try and define what should happen, which resulted in either the applet or HTML getting focus, and that was it (as far as the keyboard went).
2. Then there is the matter of the PLAF of the applet which mimics, but never quite matches that of the elements used for HTML forms.  Especially if they are styled, and that brings me to..
3. Applets do not respond to CSS!  Perhaps intuitively obvious to applet developers, but no end of frustration to the site designer.
4. Typically there is at least one version of one browser that cannot load the simplest of applets correctly. My 'favorite' of all these type of bugs was a FF version that reloaded applets if the user scrolled 'up'. I could go on, and on, and on..